# Jython: the ArrayList of an Object, which is in an ArrayList of another Object isn't created new

Tags: java, arraylist, jython

> Hello I am new to Stack Overflow hopefully you can get my Question:

I am working the first time with Jython. My goal is to use it for the ibm wsadmin-scripting, which requires either jython or cython, but only jython is an option for me. I tried build up a basic code, which will be the standard structure my Classes will have at the end.

Relationship is 1-N-N to get this i am using Arraylist for each class, which has got N Attributes.

> When i am trying to use the Arraylist, it always writes in the same List and didn't use a new created on. Hopefully my code explains the problem. I would be glad, if someone would tell me my logical problem.

```
class Student:
        name = none
        age = None

class Group:
   name = None
   studentList = ArrayList()

   def addStudent(self,stName,stAge):
     var1 = Student()
     var1.name = stName
     var1.age = stAge
     self.studentList.add(var1)

class School:
   name = None
   groupList = ArrayList()

   def createGroups(self):
      group1 = Group()
      group1.addStundent('Tim',16)
      group2 = Group()
      group2.addStudent('Lisa',15)
      group2.addStudent('Marco',16)

      for z in range(len(group2.studentList)):
         studentResult = group2.studentList[z].name
         Print 'Group2 - StudentNumber:' + str(z)+ '- Name:' + studentResult
```

> SystemOut =

```
   Group2 - StudentNumber 0- Name: Tim
   Group2 - StudentNumber 1- Name: Lisa
   Group2 - StudentNumber 2- Name: Marco
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way you initialize instance fields. In your code, all those fields are declared class fields. You have to create a constructor using the `__init__` magic word, like this:

```
class Group:
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = None
    self.studentList = ArrayList()

  def addStudent(self,stName,stAge):
    var1 = Student()
    var1.name = stName
    var1.age = stAge
    self.studentList.add(var1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply i will test it out tomorrow and give you a feedback ;)